# Find a url for a file in html using a regular expression

Tags: objective-c, regex

I've set myself a somewhat ambitious first task in learning regular expressions (and one which relates to a problem I'm trying to solve). I need to find any instance of a url that ends in .m4v, in a big html string.

My first attempt was this for jpg files

```
http.*jpg
```

Which of course seems correct on first glance, but of course returns stuff like this:

```
http://domain.com/page.html" title="Misc"><img src="http://domain.com/image.jpg
```

Which does match the expression in theory. So really, I need to put something in `http.*m4v` that says 'only the closest instance between http and m4v'. Any ideas?

Comment: what programming language...? regular expressions unfortunately has different flavors

Comment: I'm coding this for iOS, which has a new class called NSRegularExpression for this. Given a string and an expression, it returns an array of ranges matching that expression in the string. Surely it's a platform agnostic puzzle?

Comment: you could try with this expression, its pretty basic so it should work *(http|https)://.+\.4mv*

Comment: That's not going to help... that's even greedier than `.*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noticed, an expression such as the following is greedy:

```
http:.*\.jpg
```

That means it reads as much input as possible while satisfying the expression.

It's the "`*`" operator that makes it greedy.  There's a well-defined regex technique to making this non-greedy… use the "?" modifier after the "`*`".

```
http:.*?\.jpg
```

Now it will match as little as possible while still satisifying the expression (i.e. it will stop searching at the first occurrence of ".jpg".

Of course, if you have a .jpg in the middle of a URL, like:

```
http://mydomain.com/some.jpg-folder/foo.jpg
```

It will not match the full URL.

You'll want to define the end of the URL as something that can't be considered part of the URL, such as a space, or a new line, or (if the URL in nested inside parentheses), a closing parenthesis.  This can't be solved with just one little regex however if it's included in written language, since URLs are often ambiguous.

Take for example:

```
At this page, http://mysite.com/puppy.html, there's a cute little puppy dog.
```

The comma could technically be a part of a URL.  You have to deal with a lot of ambiguities like this when looking for URLs in written text, and it's hard not to have bugs due to the ambiguities.

EDIT | Here's an example of a regex in PHP that is a quick and dirty solution, being greedy only where needed and *trying* to deal with the English language:

```
<?php

$str = "Checkout http://www.foo.com/test?items=bat,ball, for info about bats and balls";

preg_match('/https?:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*((\/[^\s]*)(?=[\s\.,;!\?]))\b/i', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

It outputs:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(38) "http://www.foo.com/test?items=bat,ball"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "www"
  [2]=>
  string(4) ".com"
  [3]=>
  string(20) "/test?items=bat,ball"
  [4]=>
  string(20) "/test?items=bat,ball"
}
```

The explanation is in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for that d11wtq, I had a feeling there wasn't a 'conquers all' solution.

Comment: Something like this will do a fairly good job: `/https?:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*((\/[^\s]*)(?=[\s\.,;!\?]\s))\b/i` (Tested).  That limits the domain portion to only valid characters for a (non unicode) domain, followed by an optional path, terminated by space or a subset of punctuation marks .,;!?, only if the punctuation marks are followed by a word boundary (such as a space).

Answer (score 1):

Perl, ruby, php and javascript should all work with these:

```
/(http:\/\/(?:(?:(?!\http:\/\/).))+\.jpg)/
```

The URLs will be stored in the matched groups. Tested this out against `"http://a.com/b.jpg-folder/c.jpg http://mydomain.com/some.jpg-folder/foo.jpg"` and it worked correctly without being too greedy.

Comment: These are still greedy.  If .jpg or .m4v occur more than once in the text, they will consume everything until the last .m4v (provide the expression still satisfies).

Comment: Hmmm... interesting dilemma. I took a shot at solving it. See updated answer.